# how to run javascript code and PHP code when a variable selected from drop list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this drop down list that when I click on it, it shows me a hidden div

```
<form action="" method="post" name="select_name_form">
<input type="submit" name="select_name_submit" value="debts"/>
<select onchange="showMe(this);" name="select_name">
<?php foreach($result1 as $name) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $name['name'] ?>"><?php echo $name['name'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

</form>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMe(e) {
    var strdisplay = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var e = document.getElementById("section3");
    if(strdisplay == "Hide") {
        e.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want to make when I click on any value of this list is still shows me the hidden div but I want to apply this PHP code and select data into that div:

```
if(isset($_POST['select_name_submit'])){
    $name_selected = $_POST['select_name'];
    try{
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM debts WHERE name=:name");
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name_selected);
        $count = $stmt->execute();
        //header("location: debts.php");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        header("location: debts.php");
    }

}
```

This PHP code is in the same page where I have the drop down list. So how can I make the drop list run 2 code when a name is selected from it (one code is JS and the second is PHP).

Comment: To run PHP code from a client-side event you would need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario which you mentioned can be achieved using ajax,

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Please refer this example, you will get more idea.

in case needed, please add comment, i can help you.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: *Kya Amit Bhai ?* This is not an answer. Better, use as comment.

Comment: @NanaPartykar in case needed i can give full example here, we should actually give conceptual correct explanation, and the link gives the answer to the question.

Comment: @AmitShah just like if using JSFiddle, you should put the answer code in your answer so that others that come across this answer can see the answer without having to follow another link. They can then more easily mark your answer as helpful.